# Collapsible table bug jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a collapsible panel. The code below is the closest I got with my table, but when I collapse it in and out again, the `<td>`'s show stacked (only happens in Firefox) and in Chrome the data `<td>`'s aren't the right width after collapsed.

Also is it possible to make an image repeatedly switch? Like an green dot in the name table when collapsed and a red dot when closed?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
include "config/tabelwidth.php";
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">                                         
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("tr.header").click(function () { 
      $("tr.child", $(this).parent()).slideToggle("fast");
      $("td.subs", $(this).parent()).slideToggle("fast");
   });
});

</script>                                                               


<table border="1px" width="<?php echo $width."px"?>">
    <tr class="header">
        <td width="<?php echo $width1."px"?>">naam</td>
        <td width="<?php echo $width2."px"?>" class="subs">subs</td>
        <td width="<?php echo $width3."px"?>" class="subs">subs</td>
        <td width="<?php echo $width4."px"?>" class="subs">subs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td width="<?php echo $width1."px"?>">data1</td>
        <td width="<?php echo $width2."px"?>">data2</td>
        <td width="<?php echo $width3."px"?>">data3</td>
        <td width="<?php echo $width4."px"?>">data4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**:

ok so updating my jQuery worked!:)

I really love to see those helpful people here, seems jQuery is a really nice thing to learn ^^

If I may ask where did you guys learn jQuery?

Finally last part of my question..

let's say I want an image of an arrow pointing down (name: arrowdown) when collapsed, if hided the arrow is pointing right (name: arrowright) how'd you guys fix that one? ;o :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in Firefox 16 and Google Chrome 22 Works fine (got rid of px if that makes any difference) - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyYef/1/)
I got rid of `px` if that makes any difference.

```
<table border="1px" width="400px">
    <tr class="header">
        <td width="100">naam</td>
        <td width="100" class="subs">subs</td>
        <td width="100" class="subs">subs</td>
        <td width="100" class="subs">subs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child">
        <td width="100">data1</td>
        <td width="100">data2</td>
        <td width="100">data3</td>
        <td width="100">data4</td>    
    </tr>
</table>​
```

Ideal solution would be to create a CSS sprite and toggle its background position

### Edit

Upgrade your jQuery, I see you are using jQuery 1.3.2 and loks like there is a bug which sets `<tr>` display property to `block` instead of `table-row`

[image: debug]

Comment: didn't work for me =\ its still on http://leeuwarden.forumroc.nl/ can you check there?

Comment: The reason it isn't working nicely on your site is due to the way you're toggling visibility. When your `.slideToggle()` call kicks in to return visibility - it is setting the row to `display: block;` which is going to mess up the rendering on your table completely. This is one of the reasons a purely CSS solution is preferrable.

Comment: Upgrade your jQuery, since I see is being set as display:block instead of display:table-row

Comment: Notice, even my fiddle doesnt work when I use jQuery 1.3.2 http://jsfiddle.net/nyYef/2/

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of what you're asking can be done with a few CSS rules and a very simple jQuery toggle. I have posted an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2BbUw/

The essential gist is that you create CSS rules which force only the first row's first child to be visible when in `.collapsed` mode - and then use jQuery to toggle the `.collapsed` tag on the table itself.

The jQuery then becomes extremely simple:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table.collapsible tr:first-child').on('click', function(ev) {
        $(ev.target).closest('table.collapsible').toggleClass('collapsed');
    });​
});

// note that the above only works in later versions of jQuery, due to .on()
// If you are using an earlier version of jQuery, replace .on() with .bind()
```

The handler points only at the `tr:first-child` (the first row in the table). Because this is all CSS-selector based, it will also automatically apply to ALL `.collapsible` tables in your page.

The CSS is a little more complex, because it uses a series of pseudo-selectors:

```
table.collapsible {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

table.collapsible td {
    padding: 5px;
}
table.collapsible tr:first-child td:first-child {
    text-indent: 15px;
}

table.collapsible.collapsed tr:not(:first-child),
table.collapsible.collapsed tr:first-child td:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

For the indicator you requested - I'd propose something along the following lines. Note that this is a little rough, but again - a pure CSS solution (meaning very fast in the browser).

```
table.collapsible::before {
    content: '';
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px; top: 12px;
    height: 10px; width: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: green;
}
table.collapsible.collapsed::before {
    background-color: red;
}
```

I think you'll find that this works in all browsers - is very fast due to being all CSS toggles - and handles the various things you asked for with very simple jQuery.

Comment: the code doesnt work implented on my site =\ though thats almost exactly what i need :) (sorry if these are noob questions though i never did research in javascript, learning php and webdesign atm :p)

i did in 1 php file:
<style> style stuff </style>
<script type="text/javascript">javascript stuff</script>
table

Comment: If you put it up at your URL - I will try to debug it for you.

Comment: It's not working because you're using jQuery 1.3.2, which doesn't have an `.on` method. Try changing `.on(` to `.bind(` and it should work. Also - I am updating the script itself for your solution (it should be wrapped in a document-ready binding). Please update accordingly.

Comment: well... i updated to 1.8.3 and it still doesnt work? don't worry about it anymore btw, im using the other solution, now i just need to find out how images swap when hide / show.. ^^